# decrypt TLS in wireshark for scrapy traffic

Tags: python, encryption, https, scrapy, wireshark

I am writing crawler using [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/%20scrapy) (python module) that connects to https site (TLS 1.2). I would like to use wireshark and see what is going on. I can do this to firefox using method described [here](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/) (in short: export SSLKEYLOGFILE=... , start firefox, point wireshark to this file, enjoy). Can I do the same with scrapy?

Desired solution would be a setting for scrapy or subclass of some scrapy Middleware that would save ssl key file. Alternatively maybe this is possible for python module that handles ssl?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: I am writing crawler in python - I need help from programmers. I don't see how general tech support can help me

Comment: @MateuszL Your question can be summarized to: "I am using Scrapy to crawl SSL sites and would like to capture my Traffic with Wireshark.  Can someone please tell me how? Here's what is acceptable [list of criteria]".  As Marc B pointed out, you aren't asking for help with a programming problem, you're asking programmers for help with a problem.  The difference is akin to asking a chef why a specific unwanted outcome occurs when following a recipe vs. asking a Chef to cook you dinner.

Comment: OK, You may be right. However I believe that to solve the problem I need to modify my program so that it saves the keyfile - do in python what authors of firefox did in C/C++. This wold involve using API of either scrapy, python ssl module or whatever else is used to connect to https. I don't know what API is that and cannot find answer on my own. If You believe this can be achieved without modifying my program, please point me to stackexchange site that will be more fitting to this question.

Comment: @MateuszL, you may want to try [scrapy-users group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/scrapy-users) to ask for advice.